# how to call `org-attach` from a function?

Tags: org-attach

I would like to write a function that attaches files using `org-attach`. Unfortunately, `org-attach` only seems designed to launch a "menu", and not to be used programmatically. Since it does not accept arguments, I can't just do:

```lisp
(defun attempt1 () 
  (interactive)
  (org-attach "testfile.txt"))
```

I looked through [the `org-attach.el` source and found a `org-attach-attach` function,](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/org/org-attach.el#L483) which allows me to do:

```lisp
(defun attempt2 () 
  (interactive)
  (org-attach-attach "testfile.txt"))
```

This works but *only after* I have called `org-attach` at least once interactively.

How can I feed a file name to `org-attach` inside a function? Alternatively, how can I make sure that `org-attach-attach` is available at startup in a "fresh" emacs session, without manually calling `org-attach` first?

Comment: Looks like a clear question. Hopefully someone will have a helpful answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, my answer can be found in the [elisp manual under "Autoload"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html):

> The autoload facility lets you register the existence of a function or macro, but put off loading the file that defines it. The first call to the function automatically loads the proper library, in order to install the real definition and other associated code, then runs the real definition as if it had been loaded all along.

An easy fix is to simply add a `require` call before my function:

```lisp
(require org-attach)

(defun attempt2 () 
  (interactive)
  (org-attach-attach "testfile.txt"))
```

This makes the `org-attach-attach` function available on startup, without having to call `org-attach` manually first.